# How can get the unique total count and sum value through sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and I am trying to get the total transaction, amount and tags related to a vendor, but it show the tag successfully. I have 2 transaction to a specific vendor when i add a tag it add +1 in count it show 3 transaction and also it add the add the amount in total amount

```
                     Total_amount = 12
 transaction_name(count = 1)  amount  tag
  name                 12     test
```

if i add new tag it automatically add +1 in count and add amount

```
                 Total_amount = 24
 transaction_name(count = 2)  amount  tag
  name                         12     test, test2
```

Query

```
 SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS transactions_count,
    SUM(gt.amount) AS total_spending,
    MAX(gt.transaction_date) AS end_date,
    MIN(gt.transaction_date) AS start_date,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT loc.name, ', ') AS locations,
    (array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT gt.is_manual), false))[1] AS is_manual,
    (array_remove(array_agg(gt.is_manual is FALSE AND
      gt.company_integration_id is NULL), false))[1] AS is_imported,
    array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT t1.source), NULL) AS sources,
    array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT t2.subtype), NULL) AS plaid_subtypes,
    array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT gt_t.tag), NULL) AS tags,
    COUNT(*) OVER() AS full_count
  FROM general_transactions gt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN locations loc ON gt.location_id = loc.id
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT  g_t.tag as tag
      FROM general_transaction_tags as g_t
      WHERE g_t.general_transaction_id = gt.id
    ) AS gt_t ON TRUE
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (I doubt the above query will run on both.)

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: @jarlh Do you have any solution how can i fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what do you need in detail, but I wrote a simple query that calculates tran_count, tag_count and etc.
`general_transaction` table data:

```
id  amount  tran_date       tran_name
1   5       2022-01-08      salam
2   8       2022-01-11      sagol
3   5       2022-01-12      bizim
4   10      2022-01-03      salam
```

`general_transaction_tag` table data:

```
id      general_transaction_id      tag
2       2                           best
3       1                           test2
4       1                           test3
5       1                           test
1       1                           test
6       4                           bbtt
```

SQL Query:

```
select 
    gt.tran_name as tran_name, 
    count(distinct gt.id) as tran_count, 
    sum(gt.amount) as total_spending, 
    max(gt.tran_date) as end_date, 
    min(gt.tran_date) as start_date, 
    coalesce(string_agg(distinct gtag.tag, ', '), '') as tag,  
    count(distinct gtag.tag) as tag_count 
from 
    test.general_transaction gt 
left join 
    test.general_transaction_tag gtag on 
                        gt.id = gtag.general_transaction_id 
group by 
    tran_name
```

Result of query:

```
name    count   tot_sp  start_date  tag                     tag_count
bizim   1       5       2022-01-12                          0
sagol   1       8       2022-01-11  best                    1
salam   2       30      2022-01-03  bbtt,test,test2,test3   4
```